# Flutter: Handle user's youtube premium subscription status for embedded videos

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-data-api, subscription

I'm developing a flutter app with embedded youtube videos.

I don't really care to know the status of the user's paid subscription, I'd simply like to have the user's existing subscription status handled so they do not see ads on embedded videos within the app if they are paying for a premium subscription outside the app.

Is there a way to get a hold of (and pass on) their subscription status for embedded videos?

Any non-flutter based conversations or starting points are also welcome. For example, current investigation involves a once off webview login to the user's youtube account and then subsequently displaying youtube videos in the webview but this is obviously not ideal.

Any experience/'best approach' regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: This should happen automatically if you embed videos by [official means](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en). The browser will pass a session cookie to the embedded player so YouTube can authenticate the user (if they are logged in).

Comment: This would work on a website using an official browser, but I don't see a way an app will have access to the cookies of another app/browser. This is by design, Even if I used an embedded webview in the app, it doesn't have access to any external auth mechanisms, eg: If I was logged into gmail in chrome, there would be no access to any auth data within the app webview and the user would need to log in again.